# How to set up WebApiConfig.cs? MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

The following is the code of my WebApiConfig file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace HotelManagementSystem
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            //routes.MapHttpRoute("RestApiRoute", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" }); //this replaces your current api route


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing a lot of issues and I have been told that my code is correct and my issue lies in this file. Guys my issue is at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132648/why-isnt-ajax-sending-data) , kindly guide me as to what changes should I make.

Even the following set up did not work:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here, actually.

Your AJAX request is an HTTP Post request. In AJAX Post requests, the request payload (or data) is sent in the request's body, by default. This means that your `{ a: ab }` will not be part of the URL as in HTTP Get requests (in which case it would be appended to the end of the URL as a query string parameter: `?a=Chocolate Smoothies ya know`).

In ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI the routing is affected only by the request URL, and not the request body, therefore you do not need to define a parameter in the route template which maps to your `api/Booking/lander` route. A route like this one should be enough:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

Now, how will your action know where to look for the `a` argument, if you're not specifying it in the route template, right? Well, you just need to tell it to look in the request's body. This is done using the `[FromBody]` attribute, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public void lander([FromBody]string a)
```

Now, this tells the action that the request's body **IS** the parameter `a`. Therefore, your AJAX call needs to send a `string`, rather than an object containing the `string` (and since it is no longer an object, but a plain string, you'll need to specify the correct `contentType` for the server to parse it correctly):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/Booking/lander",
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: ab
})
```

### Edit:

Just for completeness: if you still wish the `data` in your AJAX call to remain an object (`{ a: ab }`), you'll need to define a custom model type for that data:

```
public class LanderData {
    public string a { get; set; }
}
```

and then use it as the type of the parameter in your `lander` action:

```
[HttpPost]
public void lander([FromBody]LanderData data)
```

### Edit 2:

The `[FromBody]` attribute is actually the default in `[HttpPost]` actions, so it isn't mandatory. In any case, it never hurts to be explicit.

### Edit 3:

Pay attention that when sending the data as a string instead of object, you need to make sure that it is serialized to a valid JSON string. For that end, you need to enclose your string in an additional pair of single quotes, as in `'"Chocolate Smoothies ya know"'`. This way your request body will be `"Chocolate Smoothies ya know"` which is a valid JSON string, while in the previous case it was `Chocolate Smoothies ya know`, which isn't.

Comment: A really well structured answer but unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: You need to enclose the string in additional quotes: `'"Chocolate Smoothies ya know"'`.
See edit 3 above for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

per your linked question, Well you are getting null in API endpoint cause you have declared the parameter to be optional parameter which default to `NULL` by saying `string a = null`.

Now your second question: why parameter not getting binded; because of your declared route which is the default one as below

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And observe your request below

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Booking/lander",
        method: "post",
        data: { a: ab } <-- this part
    })
```

Sole reason it's not binding automatically is, your route specifies the parameter name as `id` but your parameter name is `a`.

You should declare a separate route for this then like

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "lander",
            routeTemplate: "api/Booking/lander/{a}",
            defaults: new {controller = "lander", a = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I received a tiny syntax issue. let me put that in your edits

Comment: although i used a comma to fix it

Comment: @AsbahQadeer, yes got it .. edited .. check edit in answer

Answer (score 0):

The line `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",` should be changed to `routeTemplate: "Api/{controller}/{id}",`

Comment: After that, I can't target my controllers individually by their name? How is that even a solution

Comment: Why you cant specified your controller? There is place holder for `{controller}` in routeTemplate. I hope you are confused with  `RouteConfig.cs` which contains definition for controller and action.